# jsPDF show loading while processing. Promise does not wait

Tags: javascript, jspdf, jspdf-autotable

I'm using JSPDF and autotables plugin for PDF reports. While the PDF generation is happening I'm trying to show a loading image. Unfortunately, the loading is ignored even when trying with async().

```js
function createPDF(){
  return new Promise(resolve => {
   var doc = new jsPDF();
    doc.autoTable({
        body: [
            ['Elmo', 'Hello'],
            ['Bert', 'The Muppet Show.']
        ]
    });
    
    // mimik time for processing
    setTimeout(function(){
      console.log('wait time for loading image')
    }, 8000);

    doc.save('table.pdf');
    resolve('resolved');

    });
}

async function asyncPDF() {
  document.getElementsByClassName('img__loading')[0].style.display = 'block';
  var result = await createPDF();
  document.getElementsByClassName('img__loading')[0].style.display = 'none';
}

document.getElementById('save').addEventListener("click", asyncPDF );
```

```css
.img__loading{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.5.3/jspdf.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf-autotable/3.1.1/jspdf.plugin.autotable.min.js"></script>


<button id="save">save</button>
<img src="https://ui-ex.com/images/transparent-background-loading.gif" class="img__loading">
```

The question is why is the loading image not showing up? And why does it start working when wrapping the save() and resolve() inside the timeout?

```
  setTimeout(function(){
      doc.save('table.pdf');
      resolve('resolved');
  }, 8000);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`promise.then`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) instead of async .And for testing your setTimeout was wrong place.You need to wrap with `resolve` .While on click your async function trigger all the inner calls.so loading as been immediately disappear after present that why wrap with in then function.`then` only detect the event finished from promise

```js
function createPDF(){
  return new Promise(resolve => {
   var doc = new jsPDF();
    doc.autoTable({
        body: [
            ['Elmo', 'Hello'],
            ['Bert', 'The Muppet Show.']
        ]
    });

      console.log('wait time for loading image')


    doc.save('table.pdf');
    setTimeout(()=>{
    resolve('resolved');
    },3000)

    });
}

function asyncPDF() {
  document.getElementsByClassName('img__loading')[0].style.display = 'block';
  createPDF().then(()=>{
  document.getElementsByClassName('img__loading')[0].style.display = 'none'})
}

document.getElementById('save').addEventListener("click", asyncPDF );
```

```css
.img__loading{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.5.3/jspdf.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf-autotable/3.1.1/jspdf.plugin.autotable.min.js"></script>


<button id="save">save</button>
<img src="https://ui-ex.com/images/transparent-background-loading.gif" class="img__loading">
```

Comment: What is the difference between wrapping the pdf creation in a promise and hiding 'img__loading' in the setTimeout?

Answer (score 2):

The right answer is:

```js
doc.save('export.pdf', { returnPromise: true }).then(() => {
  // Code will be executed after save
});
```

Use a `setTimeout` to fake a promise is a bad practice.

Answer (score 1):

You've wrap it into `Promise` which is good but it's resolved immediately just because there no place where it should wait. `setTimeout` works because you call `resolve` after certain amount of time.

In `jsPDF` site you can find API of `save` method:
http://raw.githack.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/docs/jsPDF.html#save

Option that you can be interested in is `returnPromise`.

So that's should do the job:

```
await doc.save('table.pdf', {returnPromise: true});
```

Unfortunately I'm not familiar with `jsPDF` library nor autotable plugin so forgive any library related errors.

Answer (score 0):

I think the loader doesn't have enough time. Your pdf related stuff is done too quickly, promise resolves and loader hides, so it works as follows:

```
// show loader
// creating pdf took several milliseconds
// hide loader
```

When you use `setTimeout` you put off the promise resolving for 8 seconds.

```
setTimeout(function(){
      doc.save('table.pdf');
      resolve('resolved'); // resolve is also postponed
  }, 8000);
```

So the loader is shown for 8 seconds. User has enough time to see it.

Also, it a good practice to use setTimeout to unload the main thread from some heavy operation as long as you are manipulation DOM at the same time. However, using [WebWorkers](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/DOM/Using_web_workers) would be the best solution